# Path config on Navigation By cedet

Tags: emacs, cedet

I want to use cedet to navigate in my program. I use **semantic-ia-fast-jump** to jump to the declaration, and **semantic-analyze-proto-impl-toggle** to  jump to implementation. I found this two command need the files in the same dirctory. So I need to add all of the directories to the search path. I refer to a guy from the internet. the code like as follow:

```
(setq semanticdb-project-roots (list (expand-file-name "~/")))    
(defconst cedet-user-include-dirs    
  (list "~/samuel/project/modules/MManage/inc"    
        "~/samuel/project/modules/MManage/src"    
        ...
   ))    
(require 'semantic-c nil 'noerror)    
(let ((include-dirs cedet-user-include-dirs))    
  (mapc (lambda (dir)    
         (semantic-add-system-include dir 'c++-mode)    
         (semantic-add-system-include dir 'c-mode))    
          include-dirs))
```

I have several modules , so I need to add many directories. It's not converient and not portable. I think it must be a good way to config this.

PS： refer to  http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html#sec6
My setting like following

```
    (ede-cpp-root-project "library_samuel"
:name "library_samuel project"
:file (expand-file-name "~/samuel/project_self/library_samuel/CMakeLists.txt")
:include-path '("/common/include"  "/modules/MManage/inc" "/modules/ImageProcess/inc" )
:spp-table '(("BUILD_APP" . "")))
```

**semantic-ia-fast-jump** can work well, but the **semantic-analyze-proto-impl-toggle** can't work . It seems that the head and source files must in the same directories. how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to setup projects (look to [my article on CEDET](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html#sec6), for example). And inside the project, you can refer to relative paths using `include-path` directive

Comment: Thanks Alex Ott, I have read your article before. In That time ,I didn't understand the part "How to customize Semantic to work with C & C++ project" . I thought its belong to the EDE. And I only need the Semantic part. Thanks again

Comment: Hi Alex Ott. I have set the "ede-cpp-root-project" like you said 
 Now it's no problem to jump to the declaration. But it can't work on "semantic-analyze-proto-impl-toggle" to the definition.  I found out that only the head and source files in the same directory. It can work.

Comment: this is my setting:
(ede-cpp-root-project "library_samuel"
:name "library_samuel project"
:file (expand-file-name "~/samuel/project_self/library_samuel/CMakeLists.txt")
:include-path '("/common/include" "/modules/MManage/inc"            "/modules/ImageProcess/inc" ))

Comment: Hmmm, I hadn't looked to proto-impl-toggle source code, but it should work independently on location, I need to investigate this

Comment: Alex, thanks a bunch for your tut, I finally got semantic analysis basics.